# Copy Data From 1 Database to Other Using IF

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Hi i have 2 databases in local host i want to copy UPC field from one to other if their product models are same?

I have tried this:

> ```
> USE `medway_opencart` , `medway_eski_bakkal` 
> UPDATE `medway_opencart.product` 
> SET `medway_opencart.product.upc` = `medway_eski_bakkal.product.upc`
> WHERE `medway_opencart.product.model` = `medway_eski_bakkal.product.model`
> ```

And i am getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `medway_eski_bakkal` UPDATE `medway_opencart.product` SET `medway_opencart.' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the first line, no need to use any database unless your using fully qualified name(db.table)

```
UPDATE `medway_opencart.product` 
SET `medway_opencart.product.upc` = `medway_eski_bakkal.product.upc`
WHERE `medway_opencart.product.model` = `medway_eski_bakkal.product.model`
```

Unless you have priviledge to access both the databases..